# PHP variable links?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to echo a link to the bio of a certain person by clicking on his name and the quotations are getting really confusing...

echo("http://localhost/grav1ty/bio.php?bio=".$_SESSION['username'].'>$_SESSION['username']");

gives me an error message:

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'username' (T_STRING) in C:\UwAmp\www\grav1ty\mailbox.php on line 34"

Any suggestions?!

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using the mysqli extension or the PDO extension?

Comment: I'm using MySQLI

Comment: Yes, it is possible to to inject SQL with images if you do not defend against that. However, escaping binary image data is not a good idea. Instead you can use binding. Binding is always better than escaping. For a tutorial see: https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection As a final remark: It's also better not to store images in a database, they are files, not data, and belong in the file system. Store the location of the image, in the file system, in the database instead.

Comment: Why just not try to echo your query before insert it on db and see how the $fileDestination is showed. Consider use it directly as path or use double before concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

for string value use quote

```
INSERT INTO posts (posterid, posterusername, path) 
 VALUES (1, 'grud', 'uploads/5bb081a7dbb660.55196915.png')
```